# Table with txt file lines per row

Tags: php, html

I've created a system where each line of a text file **should** be on seperate lines of a table. Table design = https://puu.sh/AfCS7/d7448511ce.png

However, multiple lines look like = https://puu.sh/AfCSL/55e9cd41a3.png

My frontend.php (which manages the table) =

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Module</th>
        <th scope="col">Username</th>
        <th scope="col">Time</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
      $file = file("files/logs.txt");
      if ($file) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($file as $lines)
        {
          $linesSplit = preg_split('~,~', $lines, 4);

          echo  '<td>' . $linesSplit[0] . '</td>
          <td>' . $linesSplit[1] . '</td>
          <td>' . $linesSplit[2] . '</td>
          <td>' . $linesSplit[3] . '</td>';

        }
        echo '</tr>';
      }
      ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My backend.php (which adds each action to the logs.txt) =

```
$logsFile = fopen($logfile, 'a');

fwrite($logsFile, $firstline . ', ' . $_SESSION['user'] . ', ' . $currentDate . ' - ' . $currentTime . ', Status changed to PROG' . "\n");

fclose($logsFile);
```

I have similar table which manages each line & multiple files in a directory, i cannot understand why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance, even more so if this is stupidly easy.

Comment: Include `<tr></tr>` tags inside the loop

Comment: Unrelated to presentation - use **fputcsv** to write the CSV file

Comment: Thank you @Erwin i'm an idiot :P

Comment: Will check that out @user2182349

Comment: Try to add <br> for "next line"?